# Show score before points exam class

Tags: exam

I have created a short test with questions *(sorry for the German text, it shouldn't matter though)*:
[image]

**Is it possible to have space for a score before the maximum points added?**
I'm envisioning something like [____ / 18 VP]. This should not apply to partial points, but only the total points of a question.

[Minimum Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/477/should-minimal-examples-be-required-or-just-encouraged-for-questions-to-be-ans/479#479):

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\pointpoints{VP}{VP}
\bracketedpoints

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}

\question[18] Gebe bei Verben die Stammformen und bei Substantiven Genitiv und Genus an, als auch die Bedeutung der folgenden Vokabeln. Die Zahl in Klammern zeigt die Anzahl erwarteter Bedeutungen.
\begin{parts}
\part[2] blablabla
\end{parts}

\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can customize the points format with `\pointformat` (see documentation section 4.3.7).

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\pointpoints{VP}{VP}
%\bracketedpoints
\pointformat{[\underline{\hspace{2em}}/\thepoints]}

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}

\question[18] Gebe bei Verben die Stammformen und bei Substantiven Genitiv und Genus an, als auch die Bedeutung der folgenden Vokabeln. Die Zahl in Klammern zeigt die Anzahl erwarteter Bedeutungen.

\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Actually, when I have parts of questions, they will now also feature the underscore. How to only make the underscore apply for "main" questions? Edited my question to clarify this.

Comment: Fixed it by adding `\bracketedpoints` before every part question.

Comment: I was going to suggest using `\totalformat` and `\droptotalpoints`, but that would put the total points at the end of every question, not the beginning. Glad you found a solution that works for you though.